# Is it possible to run .bat file using javascript in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, batch-file

I want to know is it possible to run a bat file using javascript from chrome. I tried using ActiveXObject

```
MyObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
function Runbat()
{
    MyObject.Run("../test.bat");
}
Runbat();
```

But this is not working on chrome. From my search i understand it works only on IE. So is there any other way to do this?

Comment: An extension with [nativeMessaging host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) is probably the only available method.

Comment: If you can modify client machines you can register a custom url protocol that launches an app that receives the .bat file as a uri and executes it.

Comment: No i don't have access to client machine.

Comment: Then no, as said you need an extension and a custom application written to interact with it.